# How to place checkbox in DatagridView in the 6th Column of my table

Tags: vb.net

How can i move the checkbox in the 6th column. I tried putting 6 on this code but it does not work.

```
Dim chkbox As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    DataGridView4.Columns.Insert(6, chkbox)
```

[image]

Comment: Set the `DisplayIndex` property of your column(s) appropriately.

Comment: im sorry but how?

Comment: We shouldn't need to teach you the basics here. If we tell you which property to set or which method to call, you should be able to set that property or call that method. If you don't know how to set properties or call methods then you need to learn the basics first, in which case you should spend some time with a beginners tutorial. If you know how to set a property then you can do as instructed. Of course, you could do as you ALWAYS should do when introduced to a new type or member: use the Help menu in VS and read the documentation for that type or member.

Comment: What do you mean by "***it does not work***"?

Comment: i this line by putting 6 and to place the column DataGridView4.Columns.Insert(6, chkbox)

Comment: Your code works for me. Remember that the Columns collection is zero based so a new column will be inserted at position 5

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 ' Create new column of type: DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
Dim checkCol As DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn = New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
checkCol.HeaderText = "CheckBox Column"

' Add this column to the DataGridView
DataGridView4.Columns.Add(checkCol)
DataGridView4.AutoGenerateColumns = False
' If for example CheckBox Column was 12th index change it to 5 (0,1,2,3,4,5)
DataGridView4.Columns(12).DisplayIndex = 5
```